# int[][] cannot be converted into int

Tags: java

error : int[][] cannot be converted into int

Line: 4

```
class te {
public static int r,c;
public static double [][] add(double a[][],double b[][]){
    int c[][] = new int[r][c];
    for(int i = 0;i<=r;i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j<=c;j++){
            c[i][j] = a[i][j] + b[i][j];
        }
    }
    return c;
}
```

}

Comment: Which line is the error for?

Comment: Remember to always start class names with a Capital letter: class Te.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Four things:

1. The locally defined `c` *shadows* the `static` field of the class with the same name. Don't do that, as it leads to confusion, and in this case leads to a compilation error. Let's rename it to `z`.
2. That locally defined `c` is an array of `int[][]`, and you are attempting to use it as the return value of the function. The latter is defined as `double[][]`. So the compiler complains. Use `double z[][] = new double[r][c];` instead.
3. replace `i <= r` with `i < r` and ditto for `j <= c`.
4. Java conventions mandate class names to use "CamelCase". Rename it to `Te`.

(1) and (2) will fix the compile errors, (3) an array out of bounds error that you'd get at run-time. (4) will help make your code readable.